# How to load tab items dynamically in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**AppsTab.vue**

```js
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    tabList: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    variant: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: () => "vertical",
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      activeTab: 1,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div
    :class="{
      'flex space-x-4': variant === 'horizontal',
    }"
  >
    <ul
      class="list-none bg-blue-900 bg-opacity-30 p-1.5 rounded-lg text-center overflow-auto whitespace-nowrap"
      :class="{
        'flex items-center mb-6': variant === 'vertical',
      }"
    >
      <li
        v-for="(tab, index) in tabList"
        :key="index"
        class="w-full px-4 py-1.5 rounded-lg"
        :class="{
          'text-blue-600 bg-white shadow-xl': index + 1 === activeTab,
          'text-white': index + 1 !== activeTab,
        }"
      >
        <label
          :for="`${_uid}${index}`"
          v-text="tab"
          class="cursor-pointer block"
        />
        <input
          :id="`${_uid}${index}`"
          type="radio"
          :name="`${_uid}-tab`"
          :value="index + 1"
          v-model="activeTab"
          class="hidden"
        />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <template v-for="(tab, index) in tabList">
      <div
        :key="index"
        v-if="index + 1 === activeTab"
        class="flex-grow bg-white rounded-lg shadow-xl p-4"
      >
        <!-- <slot :name="`tabPanel-${index + 1}`" /> --> want to get data using loop inside tab
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

**App.vue**

```js
< script >
  import AppTabs from "./components/AppTabs";

export default {
  components: {
    AppTabs,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      tabList: ["Tab 1", "Tab 2", "Tab 3", "Tab 4"],
    };
  },
}; <
/script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-300 to-blue-500 min-h-screen">
    <app-tabs
      class="w-11/12 lg:w-10/12 mx-auto"
      :tabList="tabList"
      variant="horizontal"
    >
{{value}} // want to bind data inside tab
    </app-tabs>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Expected Output**
[image: Expected Output]

I am working on vertical tabs. Where the functionality is working fine. Here is the complete working code with static mock data https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-js-tabs-forked-we2cx?file=/src/App.vue

Now i want to create some mockdata inside of my data like 'tabList' and then, i want to display data dynamically when user clicked on tabs(including content -->tabs)

How to remove static data, which is inside slots and then only use data dynamically

To start with that, i am not sure, Where to start the looping to display data inside tabs dynamically with mock data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set dynamic slot name using `:slot="slotName"` where `slotName` is a dynamic value

This can be achieved using a `v-for` aswell like below.

```
<template v-for="content in contentList" :slot="content.slot">
  {{ content.content }}
</template>
```

Where `contentList` is your array something like below.

```
contentList: [
  { id: 1, slot: "tabPanel-1", content: "Content 1" },
  { id: 2, slot: "tabPanel-2", content: "Content 2" },
  { id: 3, slot: "tabPanel-3", content: "Content 3" },
  { id: 4, slot: "tabPanel-4", content: "Content 4" },
]
```

[Working Fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-js-tabs-forked-inb5f?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Can i also remove tabList: ["Tab 1", "Tab 2", "Tab 3", "Tab 4"],  and <app-tabs :tabList="tabList"> in App.vue and use the contentList array----> slot field to display there.

Comment: @markerj Sorry?? I didnot get that requirement, can you please explain?

Comment: Instead of taking two array called 'tabList' , 'contentList' in App.vue. to display separately for tab name and content name. Can i use only one array called 'contentList'.

because in 'contentList' array, i have slot and content. can i use only one array?

Comment: Yes you can, a sample implementatiion, https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-js-tabs-forked-4x7gz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thanks. This is Exactly what I need. One last thing, Can I call entire component in App.vue component like this https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-js-tabs-forked-o6ofc?file=/src/App.vue